# Keep getting Terraform Error for S3 Replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, syntax, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run s3 replication in terraform which will be cross-regional. Most of my code is good but I am only getting some errors which I cannot seem to solve.

Part of my main s3.tf is

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_replica-us-west-2-key" {
  description             = "S3 master key replica us-west-2"
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
  enable_key_rotation     = "true"
}

module "s3_replica" {
  source = "git@github.com:xxx"

  providers = {
    aws     = "aws.us-west-2"
  }

  name                  = "s3_replica"
  logging_bucket_prefix = "s3_replica"
  versioning            = var.versioning
  bucket_logging        = var.bucket_logging
  logging_bucket_name   = var.logging_bucket_name

  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.s3_replica-us-west-2-key.key_id
  sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm
}

module "s3" {
  source                = "git@github.com:xxxx"
  name                  = "s3"
  logging_bucket_prefix = "s3"
  versioning            = var.versioning
  bucket_logging        = var.bucket_logging
  logging_bucket_name   = var.logging_bucket_name

  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.s3.key_id
  sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm

  replication_configuration = {
    role = aws_iam_role.s3_replication.arn

      rules = {
         id = module.s3
         prefix = ""
         status = "Enabled"

        destination = {
          bucket = module.s3_replica.bucket_arn
          replica_kms_key_id = aws_kms_alias.s3_replica-us-west-2-key.arn
          storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
          }
        }

      source_selection_criteria = {
          sse_kms_encrypted_objects = {
            enabled = true
          }
        }
  }
}
```

and the part of my replication configuration block in the module I use is:

```
dynamic "replication_configuration" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.replication_configuration)) == 0 ? [] : [var.replication_configuration]

    content {
      role = replication_configuration.value.role

      dynamic "rules" {
        for_each = replication_configuration.value.rules

        content {
          id       = lookup(rules.value, "id", null)
          priority = lookup(rules.value, "priority", null)
          prefix   = lookup(rules.value, "prefix", null)
          status   = lookup(rules.value, "status", null)

          dynamic "destination" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "destination", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "destination", {})]

            content {
              bucket             = lookup(destination.value, "bucket", null)
              storage_class      = lookup(destination.value, "storage_class", null)
              replica_kms_key_id = lookup(destination.value, "replica_kms_key_id", null)
              account_id         = lookup(destination.value, "account_id", null)
            }
          }

          dynamic "source_selection_criteria" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {})]

            content {

              dynamic "sse_kms_encrypted_objects" {
                for_each = length(keys(lookup(source_selection_criteria.value, "sse_kms_encrypted_objects", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(source_selection_criteria.value, "sse_kms_encrypted_objects", {})]

                content {

                  enabled = sse_kms_encrypted_objects.value.enabled
                }
              }
            }
          }
}
```

Now when I run terraform init... it works.
But when I run terraform plan I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 321, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":"s3_bucket":
 321:           id       = lookup(rules.value, "id", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "id.s3_replication"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 321, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket": "s3_bucket":
 321:           id       = lookup(rules.value, "id", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is ""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 321, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket": "s3_bucket":
 321:           id       = lookup(rules.value, "id", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "Enabled"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 322, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 322:           priority = lookup(rules.value, "priority", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "id.s3_replication"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 322, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 322:           priority = lookup(rules.value, "priority", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is ""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 322, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 322:           priority = lookup(rules.value, "priority", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "Enabled"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 323, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 323:           prefix   = lookup(rules.value, "prefix", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "id.s3_replication"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 323, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 323:           prefix   = lookup(rules.value, "prefix", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is ""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 323, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 323:           prefix   = lookup(rules.value, "prefix", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "Enabled"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 324, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 324:           status   = lookup(rules.value, "status", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "id.s3_replication"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 324, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 324:           status   = lookup(rules.value, "status", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is ""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 324, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 324:           status   = lookup(rules.value, "status", null)
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "Enabled"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 327, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 327:             for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "destination", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "destination", {})]
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "id.s3_replication"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 327, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 327:             for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "destination", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "destination", {})]
    |----------------
    | rules.value is ""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 327, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 327:             for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "destination", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "destination", {})]
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "Enabled"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 338, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 338:             for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {})]
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "id.s3_replication"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 338, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 338:             for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {})]
    |----------------
    | rules.value is ""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 338, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 338:             for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {})]
    |----------------
    | rules.value is "Enabled"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.
```

Now I do not know why I get these errors..

- I have tried changing my rules.value which is the 'id' to so many different values but it just keeps on giving the same errors..
- These all errors solved because of @Marcin .. thank u.
- But now I got new errors:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 321, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 321:           id       = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "id", null)
    |----------------
    | replication_configuration.value.rules is tuple with 1 element

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 322, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 322:           priority = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "priority", null)
    |----------------
    | replication_configuration.value.rules is tuple with 1 element

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 323, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 323:           prefix   = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "prefix", null)
    |----------------
    | replication_configuration.value.rules is tuple with 1 element

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on .terraform/modules/s3/main.tf line 324, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket":
 324:           status   = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "status", null)
    |----------------
    | replication_configuration.value.rules is tuple with 1 element

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.
```

- please help me fix the dynamic block I am using.. I have been stuck on this since forever and cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need for each in `dynamic "rules"`, as you have only one rule in `replication_configuration.value.rules` and there is nothing to iterate over expect the actual values of this single rule.

It should be:

```
          id       = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "id", null)
          priority = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "priority", null)
          prefix   = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "prefix", null)
          status   = lookup(replication_configuration.value.rules, "status", null)
```

This will still probably lead to other errors as your dynamic blocks are very complex and difficult to understand, and would need to be re-written to make it work.

Or maybe, just changing your input value to list of rules will work without fully changing your dynamic blocks:

```
  replication_configuration = {
    role = aws_iam_role.s3_replication.arn

      rules = [
             {
         id = module.s3
         prefix = ""
         status = "Enabled"

        destination = {
          bucket = module.s3_replica.bucket_arn
          replica_kms_key_id = aws_kms_alias.s3_replica-us-west-2-key.arn
          storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: thank uu .. this helped in removing the current errors but I just got more. I need help in solving this. I have been stuck on this replication since 2 weeks and cant seem to figure it out. Can you pleasee help me modify my dynamic block? I have updated my question.

Comment: @mgb Hi. No problem. I think it would be better to make new question for the new errors.

Comment: Hey @Marcin .. thank u!! I made a new question pls check ty